# How to extract information in a dictionary in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
data = 

{'gems': [{'name': 'garnet', 'colour': 'red', 'month': 'January'},
  {'name': 'emerald', 'colour': 'green', 'month': 'May'},
  {'name': "cat's eye", 'colour': 'yellow', 'month': 'June'},
  {'name': 'sardonyx', 'colour': 'red', 'month': 'August'},
  {'name': 'peridot', 'colour': 'green', 'month': 'September'},
  {'name': 'ruby', 'colour': 'red', 'month': 'December'}]}
```

How do I create a list of colours and then just find the months with the colour red?

I've tried for and if, but I keep getting the error message

string indices must be integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have dictionaries within a list, you can use a list-comprehension with nested if logic to filter out those values you don't want:

```
[x['month'] for x in data['gems'] if x['colour'] == 'red']
```

Returns:

```
['January', 'August', 'December']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that one wants the output as a dataframe, one can use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) as follows

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['gems']).query('colour == "red"')['month']

[Out]:

0     January
3      August
5    December
```

If one wants the index to be reset, one needs to pass [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) as

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['gems']).query('colour == "red"')['month'].reset_index(drop=True)

[Out]:

0     January
1      August
2    December
```